# Cubic polynomial missing the linear term

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$$x^3+4x^2+1=0$$

This is the first homework assignment for my precalculus class. The first problem I could solve:
$$x^2+4x+1=0$$
$$(x+2)^2-3=0$$
$$x=-2\pm\sqrt3$$
I've been away from maths for a bit, so I purchased a few books of self-teaching from prealgebra to precalculus (*The Complete Idiot's Guide to Precalculus*, *Pre-Calculus for Dummies*, *Precalculus Mathematics in a Nutshell*, *Practical Algebra*). They do not seem to contain a problem like mine and if they do have something close, I was able to work that problem out cleanly.

My friend who has gone through his maths track already attempted to solve this and could not. He suggested using Wolfram Alpha, which I did, but I got back a completely wonky pair of complex roots:
$$x=-\frac43+\frac83 (1\pm i\sqrt3)\sqrt[3]{\frac2{155-3\sqrt{849}}}
+\frac16(1\mp i\sqrt3)\sqrt[3]{\frac{155-3\sqrt{849}}2}$$

Comment: Which tools do you already have for solving cubics?

Comment: MathJax in the question is completely free. And I'll _give_ you enough reputation to post more links.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha (which is [free on the web](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x^3%2B4x^2%2B1%3D0)) does indeed show that the roots are pretty horrible. Unless you're supposed to have learned about Cardano's formula (which doesn't seem likely for a first exercise), are you sure you're supposed to find an exact solution rather than a numeric approximation?

Comment: To be honest, I could not answer in terms of tools to solve cubics. I just don't remember and these books did not cover any complex nor edge cases that don't work out clean with sum of perfect cubes, difference of perfect cubes, or reducing the max n degree to a quadratic. Also, the method of providing the answer in the form with the arrows to and from the x variable, I do not know what that is called; surely there is a name for that method, but I can't seem to google it properly.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The answer is supposed to be in a form such as the answer to the first question, which ends up with the exact solution, not an approximation. I could not get wolfram alpha to give me the exact answers and their step by step solution was quite literally pages long.

We have also not learned Cardano's formula. I actually read about that before posting and it seems that's actually what wolfram is using(possibly).

Comment: @CollinStevens: Well, Cardano's formula does sometimes yield wonky expressions for roots that are actually nice, but that does not seem to be the case here. It's almost certainly not the case that there's a nice simple method that you're just overlooking. If an approximate solution is not accepted, I think it must be _either_ (a) a typo in the exercise, or (b) a trick question whose intended outcome is "it's not always that easy".

Comment: @HenningMakholm Well alright then. Unfortunately, that is what my friend suggested it is, a typo. Interestingly enough the next question is $x^4 + 4x^2 + 1$ and that works out cleanly to $\pm i\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt{3}}$, I believe

Comment: This is an irreducible cubic over the rationals (so in particular there are no rational roots).  Besides those two complex roots there is a single real root:
$$ -\frac{\sqrt [3]{620+12\,\sqrt {849}}}{6}-{\frac {32}{3\,\sqrt [3]{620+12\,
\sqrt {849}}}} - \frac{4}{3}$$
But you are almost certainly not expected to find that.  I agree with @HenningMakholm.

Answer (score 1):

Given the ugly roots of Wolfram, here a way of approximating these roots.

First at all applying the rule of signs (Descartes) one has 
$f (x) = x^3 + 4x^2 + 1$ and $f (-x) = - x^3 + 4x^2 + 1$ have a combined $ 0 + 1 = 1 $ sign change and then the degree being $3$ there are at least $3-1$, two non-real roots. This way we know there are two non-real roots and a real root.

Besides $f(-4)=1$ and $f(-5)=-24$ then the real root $x_1$ is between $-5$ and $-4$. You can approximate
$x_1\approx -4.06$. Hence the (approximate) quotient gives
$$f(x)\approx (x+4.06)(x^2-0.06x+0.2436)$$
Solving now the quadratic equation you have
$$x_{2,3}\approx 0.03\pm0.492646i$$
Check the degree of approximation, comparing with Wolfram, is your job.